# inline-block divs acting strange with margin-bottom

Tags: css, multiple-columns

Im trying to approach this design where i have different divs with display inline block. What im trying to do is keep the same margin bottom for all the divs but it seems like the content height of a div affects the space at the top of every div.

Here's the code and the css:

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #eee;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    width: 48%
}
```

> ## Hello Hello
>
> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
>
> ## Hello Hello
>
> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
>
> ## Hello Hello
>
> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy.
>
> ## Hello Hello
>
> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
>
> ## Hello Hello
>
> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry

Here you can see the results:
[enter link description here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/qyk6t/2/)

I dont care if the boxes have a different height but the bottom space between them have to be the same. any thoughts ? many thanks !

http://fiddle.jshell.net/qyk6t/2/

Comment: Review the answers and select the one that solved your problem by clicking on the **checkbox** near the answer. By doing this you will be helping future visitors like yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to solve this issue is using a mutiple column layout. This way you can split your content in more than one column keeping a different height for each one of your boxes.

```
.column {
    display : inline-block;
    margin: 0.7em;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 40%;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #eee;
    display : inline-block;
    margin: 0.7em;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}
```

As you can see in the [JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/YjmLK/).

There are some cool examples and guides of how use multiple columns:

- http://css.dzone.com/articles/implementing-card-ui-pattern
- http://portfolio.planetjon.ca/2012/12/31/how-to-make-a-flowing-css-gallery-layout/

Hope that helps you.

Comment: thanks a lot @eliezer, i will try it and let you know but it seems like this is the best practice i can approach in order to make this work.